# Will Allah accept the repentance of people who are not fluent in reading their prayers in salat?

Tags: salat

Assalamualaikum..
I just wanna ask and make sure.. Assume there is someone who wants to repent nasuha, but he is not yet fluent in reading his prayer. Is his repentance prayer valid and accepted?

Comment: If his repentance is sincere, then YES it's valid, whether it's in english or japanese or in non-fluent arabic, Allah speaks all languages.

Comment: Hi @muslimpro56 Thanks for the answer